# Kohana DB::select returns results as strings even when column types are ints

Tags: php, kohana

I've defined my table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `reputables` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `subject` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `verification_key` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_associated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `request_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `subject_UNIQUE` (`subject`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$
```

Executing

```
$query = DB::select() ->from( 'reputables')->where('subject', '=', $key)->as_object()->execute();
$reputable = $query->current();
```

Gives back an object, however type types of the properties are all strings, even when the db column is defined as an int. This causes a problem with json_encode because it puts double-quotes around values that should be integers.

How can I get the database to preserve column types while setting object properties?

**UPDATE:**

It looks like this might be a php issue. This does the same thing.

```
$testres = mysql_query('SELECT * from reputables WHERE id = 1');
$obj = mysql_fetch_object($testres);
```

All of $obj properties are of type string.

Comment: how do you suppose to preserve `date` type?

Comment: My (perhaps erroneous) assumption is that if that a column in the database is an integer, the type set in the object will also be an integer. Is this not true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the returned type is always string.
you can cast your columns afterwards, either using some automatic detection, using ctype_* functions or create a small routine which will query the database for the field dypes and set types accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Most PHP DB functions return strings for each data type. I'm not sure if Kohana supports this, but you basically would need to use bound parameters:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id FROM table");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bindColumn(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND)

var_dump($id); // will be an integer.
```

Note that if you use an ORM layer (Kohana's or otherwise), you could probably override the model to cast certain fields to integers when the values are loaded. Of course, this wouldn't help you out with any hand written SQL that operates outside of that context.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = (string) (Object $object) // object becomes string
$object = new $string() // amazing
```

the same thing with arrays:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) 
    $arrayObject->$key = $value;
```